# Unique objects from array based on two properties javascript

Tags: javascript, object, unique-values

lets say we have an array of objects:

```
results = [
{id: 1, name: John}, 
{id: 2, name: Gabo}, 
{id: 1, name: Anna}, 
{id: 3, name: Gabo}
{id: 1, name: Jack}, ]
```

I want function which gets all this objects which has unique id and name and it's value is not in other object.

```
results = [
{id: 1, name: John}, // unique id-name so we add to array
{id: 2, name: Gabo},  // unique id-name so we add to array
{id: 1, name: Anna},  // name is unique but object with this id already exists in array so we reject
{id: 3, name: Gabo}  // id is unique but object with this name already exists in array so we reject
{id: 1, name: Jack}, ] //etc..
```

```
results = [
{id: 1, name: John}, 
{id: 2, name: Gabo},
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: im looking for shortest solutions

Comment: "I want" is not a question but a request. StackOverflow does not work like that. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it just basically asks "please write the code for me".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` to register and then quickly check for duplicate `id` or `name`:

```
function getUniq(items) {
    const ids = new Set();
    const names = new Set();

    return items.filter((item) => {
        if (ids.has(item.id) || names.has(item.name)) {
            return false;
        }

        ids.add(item.id);
        names.add(item.name);

        return true;
    });
}
```